# Distorted orientation after taking image from device camera (portrait locked app)

Tags: android

My application is a portrait locked application. The application structure is based on one activity and multiple fragments. I am using support v4 fragments for this and fragments has nesting also. While I am trying to take pictures from the camera, for my profile update fragment. The camera app is open and I can capture and save the image. the image is getting in the `onActivityResult()` successfully.

But randomly the application orientation is getting distorted and its automatically change to landscape.Because of that, the current fragment state is missing. I locked the orientation from Manifest file as `android: screenOrientation="portrait` for my activity. This issue is mainly getting in Custom android phone (Samsung, HTC etc).  I required a directional guideline, whether I need to create a custom camera or any alternate fix for this issue.

My Camera call method from my fragment is given below:

```
 private void callCamera() {
        try {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I am getting the result in `onActivityResult()` of my Fragment as like this

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if( requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == mActivity.RESULT_OK){
                /**
                 * For Default Camera callback
                 *
                 */
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if(image != null){
                    AppUtility.mCapturedImage = image;
                    mIvProfileImg.setImageBitmap(image);

                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution will be handle it in **onSaveInstanceState** method.you cannot control camera intent rotation.setting your rotation to portrait and take picture in landscape mode it rotates your activity forcefully it loses its state.

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution for activity state loose. I added "android:configChanges="orientation" in activity session under manifest. Now its keeping the activity state.